# Nlog configuration for .net 4.8 Console application to write to DB - No logs written

Tags: c#, console-application, app-config, nlog

I have a C#.Net 4.8 Console Application where I am trying to use NLog for logging to a MSSQL database.

My application has the following:

```
private static Logger nLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("myLogger");

static void Main()
{
    nLogger.Info("ConsoleApp Started");
    // MAIN code of application
    nLogger.Info("ConsoleApp Ended");
    LogManager.Flush();
}
```

My app.config file has the following:

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog"/>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
        <section name="ConsoleApp.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
</startup>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  autoReload="true">

    <!-- the targets to write to -->
    <targets async="true">
        <target name="db" xsi:type="Database"
                connectionString="server=127.0.0.1\test;Database=TicketDB_Test;user id=USER;password=PASSWORD"
                commandType="StoredProcedure"
                commandText="[dbo].[NLog_AddEntry]">
            <parameter name="@machineName" layout="${machinename}" />
            <parameter name="@level"       layout="${level}"/>
            <parameter name="@message"     layout="${message}"/>
            <parameter name="@logger"      layout="${processname}" />
            <parameter name="@loggertype"  layout="${literal:text=ConsoleApplication}" />
            <parameter name="@properties"  layout="${all-event-properties:separator=|}" />
            <parameter name="@callsite"    layout="${callsite}"/>
            <parameter name="@linenumber"  layout="${callsite-linenumber}" />
            <parameter name="@exception"   layout="${exception:tostring}"/>
            <parameter name="@stackTrace"  layout="${stacktrace}"/>
        </target>
    </targets>
    <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
    <rules>
        <logger name="myLogger" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="db" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
<applicationSettings>
    <ConsoleApp.Properties.Settings>
        //...
    </ConsoleApp.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

The solution has the NLog and NLog.Database packages both at version 5.2.4

When the console app is run nothing is logged to the database. The stored procedure NLog_AddEntry has been checked and works.

I have ran out of ideas why NLog is not logging to the db?

Comment: Try using [NLog InternalLogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging) and look for clues. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-Troubleshooting

Comment: I'm guessing you are missing `<extensions><add assembly="NLog.Database"/></extensions>`

Comment: Alternative instead of `xsi:type="Database"` then one can use `type="Database, NLog.Database"`

Comment: @RolfKristensen Thanks for suggestions. The internal logger gave me the final answer… I had mistyped one of the parameter names in my target… great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@RolfKristensen Thanks for suggestions. The internal logger gave me the final answer… I had mistyped one of the parameter names in my target… great help.